# Kerberos authentication with Java EWS API

Tags: kerberos, exchangewebservices

I am making use of [EWS JAVA API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) to connect and retrieve data from EWS. Currently I can successfully do so via NTLM authentication, providing my username and password in code:

```
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password", "domain");
```

However I'd like to authenticate by Kerberos instead (i.e. no explicit password specified). To give a high level picture, the interaction would be:

```
User <-> MyWebApplication <-> EWS
```

I can get hold of the user information (username, realm/ domain) in MyWebApplication. However I am not sure how I can generate the Kerberos token and pass in the Authorization (of type Negotiate) in the HTTP header to EWS using said library.

Please let me know if someone has managed to achieve something similar. In the worst case, I am open to not using the library at all and will just write my own implementation.

(I am aware of the commercial lib from IndependentSoft but not in the position to use it)

Comment: Hi @pkid169 I'm developing a new service to do NTLM authentication https://www.nafiux.com/wasp/ if I can help you please let me know

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635518/kerberos-authentication-between-java-on-linux-and-exchange-web-services-ews